# Add persistent TokenCache for ADAL 4 (experimental) - Xamarin Forms project

Tags: azure, adal, xamarin.forms

I have read that the built-in TokenCache that ships with ADAL v4 (experimental) does not persist tokens. Does anyone have an implementation that stores tokens using the file system or similar?

My project is using Xamarin Forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere in StackOverflow, anything that works in Xamarin for the experimental ADAL works by accident at this point. The scenario was not tested for the experimental library, and we already know that future refreshes of the preview will almost certainly break code based on the current one. Add to this that the preview is not meant to operate in production. Xamarin support is an important scenario to us, but this preview does not flesh it out yet. Hopefully we'll be able to make progress on that soon. I would not recommend to spend too many cycles extending the libraries at this point, and if you choose to do it anyway I just want to make sure we set the right expectations.

Comment: Thanks @vibronet. Totally understand the experimental nature of this library and not looking to use for production at this stage. What is the best place to see the status of the ADAL v4 library - NuGet?

Comment: Do you have a working example for AcquireTokenAsync (Xamarin.Forms) ? I cannot make it work